# dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

Tags: dconf

Whenever I open any software through Terminal I get following errors and eventually the software opens

```
dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(gedit:3609): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(gedit:3609): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
```

What can be the possible issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem, in my case I was running `"sudo gedit"` from a user account; therefore when it tried to save dconf changes it realized that the user was not root, and thus it raised those errors. I solved it by running gedit as a "root":

```
sudo -i

gedit &
```

where `sudo -i` will login into a user acount.

Comment: thx. that hint solved my problem. (so i had to log in via `su - myotheruser` instead of `su myotheruser`.)

Comment: ompiz --replace &

Comment: But I don't want to run `sudo -i`! gedit should still not do that.

Answer (score 6):

This has got on my nerves for a long time. I finally solved it using `gksudo -l <command>`, which runs the command in a login shell - similarly to XAVI's answer but without the need to type in the command after `sudo`.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to check if the following folders are owned by `root`:

```
~/.cache/dconf
~/.dbus
```

If they are, try deleting them. According to other sources I found, they should be owned by yourself, but if you have run graphical programs with `sudo` they might have been created by root instead. Deleting them is apparently safe, as they are automatically recreated as necessary, but maybe back them up first.

Answer (score -2):

So I had this problem also. I did not have the patience to work through the various tedious and/or ineffective solutions that I found on the interwebs. The following worked for me:

```
$ emacs foo.py 2>/dev/null &   # (assuming you have an Xserver running)
```

No, it's not elegant. But it works. I haven't run into any *bona fide* emacs stderr's for years (if ever) so how bad can this be? And you can stick in an 'alias' in your .bashrc file.

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't solve the problem :) In my case, nautilus is unable to save configuration changes (say, changing an option to show hidden files.) Doing what you suggest justs hides the error, but it doesn't solve the error.

Comment: True. But your problem is likely permissions on the dir's that contain the config files. At some point I had to track this down and fix it. [This is on Ubuntu/Wndows.]