# Fix dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf - in non-login su session

Tags: gnome, root, su, dconf

I've read this:

[dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182925/34868)

... and I have the same problem. But - I don't like the solution. I want to run a non-login root shell session, with `su` (not `su -i`); and within that session, I want to run a GNOME app (well, not really, but suppose that I do). Let's say it's gedit. How can I get such an app to *not* complain about this dconf business? It's running as root, it can do whatever it wants - what's the problem?